# jquery event not work with many div on Opera and Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, opera

On my webside I create several div with `id="bigger"`. This div should enlarge div `id="text"` and load inside (using ajax) next `subweb`.
Here is part of my code:

```
        /*ajax*/
    function ajax(src, cont){
            $.ajax({
                url: src,
                context: document.body,
                success: function(responseText) {
                    $(cont).html(responseText);
                    $(cont).find("script").each(function(i) {
                        eval($(this).text());
                    });
                }
            });
    }

    /*bigger div*/
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('div#bigger').click(function(){
            $("#text").animate({ 
            width: "1050px",
            left:"150px",
            padding:"0"
            }, 1500 );
            $('#infbox').css('display','none');
        })
    })
    <!--it's work-->
                            <div id="bigger" onClick="ajax('gallery.php', '#text')" class="slide">
                            <span id="galdesc"><p>G<br />A<br />L<br />E<br />R<br />I<br />A</p></span>
                            <img src="img/slideshow/galler2y.png" class="img" />
                        </div>
                        <div id="bigger" onClick="ajax('website.php', '#text')" class="slide">
                            <span id="webdesc"><p>S<br />T<br />R<br />O<br />N<br />Y<br /><br />W<br />W<br />W</p></span>
                            <img src="img/slideshow/website.png" class="img" />
                        </div>
                        <div id="bigger" onClick="ajax('applications.php', '#text')" class="slide">
                            <span id="webdesc"><p>P<br />R<br />O<br />G<br />R<br />A<br />M<br />Y</p></span>
                            <img src="img/slideshow/applications.png" class="img" />
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="cont">
            <div id="menu" onClick="ajax('textpl.txt','#text')"><p>MENU</p></div>
            <div id="teleadr">
                <p>e-mail:<a   href="mailto:makowskaewa@o2.pl"> makowskaewa&#64;o2.pl</a>&nbsp; &#124; &nbsp; tel: 607079560</p>
            </div>
            <div id="infbox">
                <div id="inf">
                    <p>NA STRONIE:</p>
                    <ul>
<!--this three not work on Opera and Chrome-->
                        <li><div id="bigger" onClick="ajax('gallery.php','#text')"><p>galeria</p></div></li>
                        <p>Moje prace wykonane głównie przy wykorzystaniu programów graficznych takich jak Photoshop, Gimp oraz Blender.</p><br />
                        <li><div id="bigger" onClick="ajax('website.php','#text')"><p>webmastering</p></div></li>
                        <p>Stworzone przeze mnie strony www.</p><br />
                        <li><div id="bigger" onClick="ajax('applications.html','#text')"><p>programowanie</p></div></li>
                        <p>Kilka prostych programów napisanych przy wykorzystaniu php oraz baz danych.</p>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="text">
```

Everything works correctly on Firefox, but when I use Opera or Chrome I can use only three first div `id="text"`. When I try use second three div, that should load the same `subweb` like earlier div, there is no reaction. Even pseudo-classes `:hover` does not work, and firebug  doesn't seem to see these elements.
I tried change `id="bigger"` to `class="bigger"`, and several ways to connect jquery with not one but every div with one id.

I don't have idea what to do, maybe somebody could to help me. I hope I wrote everything correctly, because my english isn't perfect.

Comment: why are you using onclick as well as binding a click event? you can use data attributes like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ukvrhqhy/1/. `p` inside `span` is not valid and ids should be unique - if you do a selector for an id, it will only use the first one that it finds as it is not expecting to find anymore

Comment: Can you provide a js-fiddle of your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Each ID has to be unique on that page. Having multiple elements with the same ID will give you problems, no matter what.

If you change your divs again to have `class="bigger"` instead of `id="bigger"` and then you adapt your code, you should get a lot further already:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('div.bigger').click(function(){
            $("#text").animate({ 
            width: "1050px",
            left:"150px",
            padding:"0"
            }, 1500 );
            $('#infbox').css('display','none');
        })
    })
```

Make sure that the `#text` ID is unique as well! It won't work if it isn't unique! Same for `#infobox`

You also should close your `<div id="text">` with `</div>`, but that might just be your example code that was cut too tightly.

[Global standard of ID attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It's incorrectly css. #infbox had position:absolute and z-index:-1, so it's cover by another layers and I did it, because then jquery effect looks better. After removed z-index:-1 everything work and look ok.